# Redirecting issue using header("Location: url.php") or form action

Tags: php, forms, redirect, authentication, action

When using `header("Location: url.php)`, the URL does not change to the new page, in our case `login.php` (so when refreshing it will just go back to the login page). If the page is placed in action in the form there is no requirement to log in. So my question now is whether anyone has any idea how we could get to the right page with the correct URL. Or perhaps anyone has any idea what may cause this.

Login.php (logic)

```
$user = new User();
if(!empty($_POST["btnLogin"])) {
  try {
    $user = new User();
    $user->Username = $_POST["username"];
    $user->Password = $_POST["password"];
    $user->Login();
  }
  catch(Exception $e) {
   $feedback_error = $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

login.php (form)

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
  <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
  <p>Not yet signed up? <a href="register.php" >Register</a></p>
  <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" data-theme="b" value="Sign in">
</form>
```

user.php (class)

```
public function Login() {
  $salt = "ab4p73wo5n3ig247xb1w9r";
  $db = new Db();
  $select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" .
    $db->mysqli->real_escape_string($this->Username) .
    "' AND password = '" .
    $db->mysqli->real_escape_string(md5($this-> Password . $salt)) . "';";
  $result = $db->mysqli->query($select);
  if($result->num_rows == 1) {
    $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
    $_SESSION["username"] = $this->Username;
    //header("Location: show_bugs.php");
  } else {
    throw new Exception("Please enter correct username and password");
  }
}
```

Comment: Crank up error reporting and see what you see. More likely then not your program is throwing useful information at you but your config is squashing it.

Comment: And anothing thing, I noticed you're using sessions. Is that being included in every affected page? I.e. `session_start();`.

Comment: If I use header(location) it only shows the content of that page, but the url isn't changing. En yes I affect them on every page

Comment: @MarnixVerhulst Are you not using `session_start();`? I didn't see it in your posted code. Your `$_SESSION["loggedin"] etc.` are useless without it.

Comment: Yes I do it on every page...

Comment: Does this page use jquery mobile?

Comment: yes it does. Is it because of that usage?

Comment: Yes, see answer below

Comment: thanks, I thought it was something like that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a known bug when using JQM. There apparently is a workaround of calling out data-ajax to be false:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" data-ajax="false">
```

Bug here - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2836

Stack overflow question - [Symfony 2 and jQuery mobile 1.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516902/symfony-2-and-jquery-mobile-1-1-1)

Comment: Can I create the form with ajax when i set data-ajax to false?

Comment: Not fully sure what you mean. You should be able to load the form via ajax, but JQM will not attempt to use ajax when the form is submitted, Plus it would be really strange to use ajax to fetch the same page you are currently on (PHP_SELF)